# SQL/jQuery/AJAX - Using <select> filter form to dynamically update div with results

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, search

I'm working on a filter box.

Player should be able to filter by changing multiple `<select>` boxes - filter by `$position`, `$minvalue` and `$maxvalue`, sort by `points`, `value`, `surname` (ascending and descending for any case). Also he  must be able to search for certain string within `name`/`surname`.

I've created a query that should make it work:

```
SELECT * FROM players 
WHERE (name LIKE '%$searchphrase%' OR surname LIKE '%$searchphrase%') 
AND position='$position' 
AND value BETWEEN $minvalue AND $maxvalue
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN $filter=0 THEN points END DESC, 
    CASE WHEN $filter=1 THEN points END ASC,
    CASE WHEN $filter=2 THEN value END DESC,
    CASE WHEN $filter=3 THEN value END ASC,
    CASE WHEN $filter=4 THEN surname END DESC,
    CASE WHEN $filter=5 THEN surname END ASC
```

The real question however is: **is it possible to make an `AJAX` query `onchange` for selects etc. that would dynamically send those variables to a php file and load this file with this specific data into a div?**

Let's say this would be my AJAX script:

```
 $(".filter").change(function() {
        post_data = {
                        'searchphrase'           : $('#searchphrase').val(), 
                        'position'               : $('#position').val(), 
                        'minvalue'               : $('#minvalue').val(), 
                        'maxvalue'               : $('#maxvalue').val(),
                        'filter'                 : $('#filterselect').val(),  
                    };

                    $.post('filteringFile.php', post_data, function(){
                        ///What should i put there?
                        /// Also what would i need in my php file to receive proper filtering in here?
                    }, 'json');
    });
```

Comment: What don't you understand? In the PHP code you use `$_POST` to get the parameters, and in the JS callback function you simply display the result in the appropriate DIV.

Comment: The parsed JSON will be the argument to the callback function. Put code there that formats it as HTML and puts that into the output DIV.

Comment: @Barmar Then how do I make the callback? I mean how to pass for example echoed string from PHP back to browser?

Comment: Change `function() { // what should I put there }` to `function(data) { ... }`. `data` will contain the parsed JSON.

Comment: Any tutorial on doing AJAX with jQuery should have examples of this.